# Cannot get R to compare seemingly equal strings

Tags: r, excel, encoding, string-matching

I recently received an excel file of unknown origin (and used excel to ouput a subset into a text file "example0.txt" (see in dropbox link below). In this dataset, two strings that appear by all means equal, cannot be compared by R.

```
a<-scan("example0.txt", what="raw")
a
[1] "ÖSTVÅG"   "FALKVÅG" "ÖSTVÅG"

# cell a[1] and a[3] appear similar ("ÖSTVÅG"). However,

a[1]==a[3]                  # I was expecting TRUE but I get FALSE
nchar(a[1]) == nchar(a[3])  # I was expecting TRUE (n=6) but I get FALSE

# and similarly,

nchar(a[2]) == 8            # I was expecting n=7
```

see files in dropbox:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hz6vsj5kj1u9ag6/AACtTMh-x4IIB10kMCUE5rvBa?dl=0

This behaviour really complicates matching strings on a larger dataset I am working on, let alone newer datasets that will be coming in.

Initially I suspected it would have to do with Encodings but I have tried reading the data with different encodings and performing conversions in R but I still get the same results.

I managed to solve the issue by opening the file in notepad and re-writing the a[3], re-saving the file afterwards and I was surprised to see that it now works (you can see the result in example0correct.txt).  even if the new file appears equal to the original one.

Can anyone explain me what is happening and how I can detect and correct this occurrences taking example0 as a starting point?

Note: Dont know if it matters, but I am using R 3.2.2 in a windows 7 machine with office 2013 installed.

Comment: The files in your dropbox do not appear to give the above result.

Comment: @Nuno Prista - Can't see the dropbox (corporate firewall); but when you compare the two files you are mentioning (example0.txt and example0correct.txt) byte by byte there must be a difference (eg. view them in hex) - did you check those?

Comment: If seems that `a[3]` contains a [Single-Shift 3 control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes). See `enc2utf8(a)`. `stringi::stri_width(a[-2])` yields `6` two times.

Comment: @lukeA thanks! I can now identify them. Is there a quick way to convert all into the same "format"? I mean: making a[3] == a[1]? I need this in order to be able to, e.g., sort the strings

Comment: Maybe via extracting only specific character classes, see ``?stringi::`stringi-search-charclass` `` and `?stringi::stri_extract_all_charclass`.